# Chrome returns error code 5 for increment click function

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I've written some code in html and javascript and when I drag it into chrome to test it, I get error code 5 in return. I've tried everything that chrome itself recommends when this happens as well as trying with different code, which works. heres my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var x = 1
        var total = 0
        var increment = 1
        setInterval(function(){ total + increment; }, 1000);
        while (x = 1) {
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#id").click(function(){
                    $("h1").text(total + 1);
                });
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>0</h1>
    <button id="id">??????????</button>
</body>
```

keep in mind, I'm extremely new to both of these languages, so I'm learning as I go.

Comment: You have an infinite loop because you x always equals 1

Comment: Additionally you’re not using Boolean in the while loop. It should be `x == 1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some issues in your code:

- your while loop runs forever since x=1 will remain true (which is causing the error), furthermore x isn't changed in the loop
- the function in setInterval is doing nothing since there is no assignment `=`

---

Anyway, you don't need the most stuff. It is enough to get the value of h1 and increment it directly. If the script tag is put before the closing body tag you don't need the `$(document).ready`-part. So the following is all javascript you need:

**Working example**:

```js
$("#id").click(function() {
  $("h1").text(parseInt($("h1").text()) + 1);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1>0</h1>
<button id="id">??????????</button>
```

---

By the way, you don't need jQuery for that and can use plain javascript.

**Working example**:

```js
document.getElementById('id').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.querySelector("h1").textContent = parseInt(document.querySelector("h1").textContent) + 1;
});
```

```html
<h1>0</h1>
<button id="id">??????????</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to declare variable `x` at all. Also, you don't need `while loop`.

Your loop will go to infinity because condition `while(x=1)` will be always **true**.

I guess infinite while loop crashes your Chrome browser.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    var total = 0

    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#id").click(function() {
        total++;
        $("h1").text(total);
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>0</h1>
  <button id="id">??????????</button>
</body>
```